# Burninate [result]

Tags: feature-request, burninate-request

I'll let a [recent suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2281292) to the tag wiki speak for me:

> A result is the final consequence of a sequence of actions or events
>   expressed qualitatively or quantitatively.
>
> Possible results include "success", "error", "input", "login", "none".
>   There may be a range of possible results associated with an event
>   depending on action code, business logic, result type. Reaching no
>   result doesn't mean that actions are inefficient, ineffective,
>   meaningless or flawed instead the result "none" is returned meaning
>   that no additional action is required.

In other words tagging a question [result](/questions/tagged/result) means that something has happened. By that rationale there's never going to be any point having this tag on any question as something will always have happened.

Can this be burninated please?

Comment: Also results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/results

Comment: **Kill it with fire!**